# Border radius not working in Safari 5

Tags: html, css, safari

I need to have 1 outer div with position:absolute and with border-radius.
Inside the outer div I might have 1 or more inner position:absolute divs.
I want that the inner divs when they are located in the border-radius of the outer div
(Example: top:0px; left:0px;) will not hide the border-radius of the outer div.

This behavior is working fine in all browser except Safari.

I need to support this behavior in Safari 5 as well as 6 and 7.
I have seen some solutions with `-webkit-mask-image` but none of them works in Safari 5.

This is an example of html I am trying to display:

```
<div style="position:absolute; background:blue; width:300px; height:300px; border-radius:30px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="position:absolute; background:red; width:200px; height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add border-radius to you inner div?

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius: inherit;` in the second div.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to simplified the problem, but actually the inner div does not have to be with the same size of the outer div. inside the outer div might be several divs in position:absolute located somewhere inside the outer div, so unfortunately this solution will not help me ):

Comment: I am lost. As far as I understand from your explanation, you have a outer div which has a specific border radius. The outer div may have one or more inner div/s, that have property position: absolute and you want to have border-radius of all inner div same as the border-radius of outer div?

If it's what you are saying, then by specifying border-radius: inherit; to all inner div, this problem is solved.

Comment: Anyway, If the inner div is smaller then the outer div and I will give the inner div border-radius as the parent div, the inner div will have some unwanted border-radius